# How to run RFID tag listener method in javafx project?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, javafx-8, rfid

I am working on a project involves RFID technology, what i am trying to do at the moment, once the `RFIDTagListener` method runs, I basically pass a tag to a reader which its serial number will be sent to a server to get some relevant data back and pop them on a GUI screen. what I have done so far is getting the data upon sending reader's data manually without passing a tag becasue I don't know how to do it otherwise and here is the problem. where I am working on a javafx project and when I tried to put the `RFIDTagListener` method within the `MainController` class and on compiling, the taglistner method wouldn't be triggered and just ignored, it's only the GUI screen will be opened.However, I also tried to have `RFIDTagListener` within the `main` class but on compiling, the `taglistner` method would be run first and when it's finished in 5 seconds, my GUI window will be opened next. SO I Don't know where this method should be located exactly. Essentially What I want is to have them both running at the same time, the `taglistener` running in the background with the GUI window opened simulitniously.

Any recommendation guys would be much appricated.

> MainController class :

```
public class MainController {
    RFID rfid = new RFID();

    String ReaderNo = null;
    String walletJson = new String();
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    public static String sensorServerURL = "http://localhost:8080/PhidgetServer2019/SensorServerRFIDdata";

    walletDAO dao = new walletDAO();
    ArrayList<wallet> allwallets = new ArrayList<wallet>();

    @FXML VBox ConsultHR;
    @FXML private Label message;
    @FXML private Label WalletName;
    @FXML private ListView<ArrayList<wallet>> list;
    @FXML private ListView<ArrayList<wallet>> RoomAList;
    @FXML private TableView<wallet> tableViewData;
    @FXML private TableColumn<wallet, String> NameColumn;
    @FXML private TableColumn<wallet, String> LocationColumn;
    @FXML private TableColumn<wallet, String> TagColumn;


    public void getTags(ActionEvent event) throws SQLException {
        allwallets = dao.getWalletTag();
        try {
            allwallets = dao.getWalletTag();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(allwallets);
        list.getItems().add(allwallets);
    }

    public MainController() throws PhidgetException {
        // Make the RFID Phidget able to detect loss or gain of an rfid card
        rfid.addTagListener(new RFIDTagListener() {
            // What to do when a tag is found
            public void onTag(RFIDTagEvent e) {
                try {
                    ReaderNo = String.valueOf(rfid.getDeviceSerialNumber());
                } catch (PhidgetException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                System.out.println("Reader serial number is " + ' '+ReaderNo);
                wallet walletData = new wallet("385055");   
                walletJson = gson.toJson(walletData);       

                String resultfromserver = sendToServer(walletJson); 
                System.out.println("DEBUG: data in json : " +resultfromserver);
                wallet  walletObject = gson.fromJson(resultfromserver, wallet.class);                       

                System.out.println("DEBUG: The wallet's Data: "+' '+ walletObject);

                WalletName.setText(walletObject.getWalletName());
            }
        });

        rfid.addTagLostListener(new RFIDTagLostListener() {
            // What to do when a tag is lost
            public void onTagLost(RFIDTagLostEvent e) {
                // optional print, used as debug here
                System.out.println("DEBUG: Tag lost: " + e.getTag());
            }
       });
    }
}
```

> Main class :

```
public class Main extends Application {
   //RFID rfid = new RFID();

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    primaryStage.setTitle("Wallet locator !");
    try {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/Main.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 public static void main(String[] args) throws PhidgetException {
    new MainController();           
    launch(args);
 }
}
```

> Main.FXML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>  
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="269.0" prefWidth="403.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.MainController">
   <Button layoutX="149.0" layoutY="251.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#getTags" prefHeight="46.0" prefWidth="82.0" text="tags" />
   <Label fx:id="message" layoutX="139.0" layoutY="209.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="101.0" />
   <ListView id="studentObservableList" fx:id="list" layoutY="209.0" prefHeight="131.0" prefWidth="139.0" />

   <TableView fx:id="tableViewData" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="231.0" style="-fx-border-color: red;">
      <columns>
         <TableColumn fx:id="NameColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="Name"/>
         <TableColumn fx:id="LocationColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="Location" />
         <TableColumn fx:id="TagColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="Tag" />
      </columns>
   </TableView>

   <Button layoutX="251.0" layoutY="14.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#getWallets" prefHeight="56.0" prefWidth="82.0" text="wallets" />
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: completely unrelated: blockquote tags are for ... guess .. quotes, nothing else ;)

Comment: Never knew that before, thanks for this golden tip bro

Answer (score 1):

**1st point**

The `main` method is inside the `MainController` class and it's instantiating itself, which is possible but not conventional.

**2nd point**

Never put your `main` method into a controller! Put it into your `Main` class instead.

**3rd point**

You must define the application launch inside your main method, by calling `Application.launch()`. This method will call your overriden `start` method (among other things) and display the GUI:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws PhidgetException {
    launch(args);
    new MainController();           
}
```

**4th point**

You don't need to instantiate directly a controller in JavaFX. With your current code you're creating a `MainController` instance which is unlinked to your GUI; that's why you can see your GUI without interacting with it. You need to remove the `new MainController();` line into your `main` method, then check if the `fx:controller` attribute is defined in the root of your FXML file.

You can call this controller instance using `root.getController()` in your `start` method.

Comment: Thank you a lot for these clarifications, I have uploaded main.fxml above. but could you re-explain how to define the controller again according to my main.fxml

Comment: When you write your FXML file, you can add an attibute to the root of your element which is `fx:controller`. This information will be used by your FXML loader to understand that your view is linked to a controller, and it will automatically create an instance of `MainController` once you start your application. Is it good for you ? :) By the way you forgot to remove the `main` method from your controller

Comment: so as I want to display data on a label, when to link this label with the controller, as far as I understood there should be an instance of the controller to link it with label right ! but I don't see where I put `root.getController()`. and does the path of my controller represent the project name below ?`<Label xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="path.to.your.controller.MainController">`

Comment: You should probably get rid of the `new MainController()` you have under `launch(args)`. The `launch` method only returns once the JavaFX runtime has exited.

Comment: You have created `root` inside your `start` method. Concerning your controller path, you're right; it starts from the root of your Java project, `application.MainController` in your case.